# Is there a word for an unjustified true belief?

Tags: single-word-requests, philosophy

Typically knowledge is formulated as justified, true, belief. Is there a word for an unjustified, true, belief?

Edit: Lets say for a moment that you think that all Asians are martial artists. This is a false and therefore not something you can use to justify something else. However, because of that, you conclude that because Jackie Chan is Asian, Jackie Chan is a martial artist. It happens to be true that Jackie Chan is a martial artist. You believe it and it's true, but it's not properly justified.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57548/discussion-on-question-by-alonzo-muncy-is-there-a-word-for-an-unjustified-true-b).

Comment: **Belief**: "an acceptance that something exists or is true, especially one without proof."

Answer (score 17):

Maybe a "lucky guess?" This phrase is often used when someone gets the right answer, but we know they have no idea why it's correct.

Comment: Yup, with the coordinate terms **blind** or **dumb luck** describing the completely unjustified nature of the answer's selection.

Comment: +1 I wonder if you knew this or had a lucky guess.

Answer (score 6):

> Is there a word for an unjustified, true, belief?

Depends how unjustified you mean.  Below are a bunch of terms that might fit.  Off-hand, it seems like ***postulate***, ***conjecture***, ***speculation***, or ***faith*** might fit, depending on what you mean by "unjustified".

- **definition**:  Defined as true, mostly used to refer to a trivially simple concept.
- **axiom**:  Defined as true, mostly used to refer to non-trivial concepts.
- **postulate**:  Believed to be true, supported by a strong sense of analytical correctness.
- **law**:  Believed to be true, supported by overwhelming evidence.
- **theorem**:  Believed to be true, supported by strong evidence.

  - In logical fields (*e.g.* math; logic; computer science), proof is more analytical and generally regarded as irrefutable unless there's a major paradigm shift in understanding.
  - In sciences, a *theory* is a very strongly evidenced belief, but not quite as strong as a *law*.
- **hypothesis**:  Suspected to possibly be true, but yet unproven.

  - Often implies a desire to seek further evidence.
- **conjecture**:  Quite plausibly true, but unproven and may be doubted.
- **speculation**:  Plausibly true, but significant reason to doubt.

  - **motivated speculation**:  Plausibly true, plus some reason to suspect it.
  - **unmotivated speculation**:  Plausibly true, without reason to suspect it.
- **faith**:  Believed to be true, but no evidence nor logical motivation.
- **false belief**:  Believed to be true, but strong evidence against.
- **delusion**:  Believed to be true, but overwhelming evidence against.
- **falsehood**:  Not believed to be true.

Comment: That's a lovely chain of definitions. It doesn't really fit *this* post at all, where OP is *specifically* asking for *un*justified but accurate belief, but you should repost it when a more fitting topic comes up.

Comment: in another of its meanings faith should go on the top of this list with "**faith:** Defined as true, mostly used to refer to a non-trivial, complex concept." You know, like religious faith and stuff.

Answer (score 3):

***tl;dr*-**  In math jargon, a ["*howler*"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Howler_(error)#Mathematics_as_a_special_case_of_terminology) is a correct result obtained through unsound reasoning.  However, this usage appears to be jargon, and the same term [can be interpreted different ways](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Howler_(error)).

---

## "*Howler*"

In math, a correct result arrived at through an unsound method has been called a ***howler***:

1. > Mathematical errors occur in many different forms. In his short treatment of the topic, E. A. Maxwell distinguished the simple mistake, which may be caused by ‘a momentary aberration, a slip in writing, or the misreading of earlier work’, from the howler, ‘an error which leads *innocently* to a *correct* result’, and the fallacy, which ‘leads by *guile* to a *wrong* but plausible conclusion’ (Maxwell, 1959, p. 9).
   >
   > We might gloss this preliminary taxonomy of mathematical error as correlating the
   >   (in)correctness of the result to the (un)soundness of the method, as in Table 1.
   >
   > ```
   >                |  True Result    False Result
   > ---------------+--------------------------------
   >   Sound Method |   Correct         Fallacy
   > Unsound Method |   Howler          Mistake
   > ```
   >
   > Table 1. A Preliminary Typology of Mathematical Error
   >
   > –"*Learning from our Mistakes—but Especially from our Fallacies and Howlers*", Andrew Aberdein ([PDF](https://my.fit.edu/~aberdein/FallaciesHowlers))
2. > #### Howlers
   >
   > ---
   >
   > Examples exist of mathematically correct results derived by incorrect lines of reasoning. Such an argument, however true the conclusion, is mathematically [invalid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Validity_(logic)) and is commonly known as a *howler*.
   >
   > –["*Mathematical fallacy*"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invalid_proof#Howlers), Wikipedia

["*Howler (error)*"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Howler_(error)), Wikipedia, discusses the word.  Apparently ***howler*** isn't commonly understood in the sense cited above, so this may be regarded as math jargon.

---

#### Note: There probably isn't a non-jargon alternative.

Apparently "*howler*" was coined in 1959, in ["*Fallacies in Mathematics*"](https://books.google.com/books?id=zNvvoFEzP8IC) by [Edwin A. Maxwell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edwin_A._Maxwell).

Since Maxwell did his PhD dissertation in Math at the University of Cambridge, and published a book on mathematical fallacies, I assume that he'd be well-aware of any preexisting term for a "*howler*" if one had existed and just used that.  Since he didn't, this seems to strongly suggest that there isn't (or at least wasn't) a non-jargon alternative.

Additionally:

2. I haven't been able to find a good term for the same searching on Google just now.
3. The above sources, including Wikipedia, don't mention any alternatives.

For these reasons, it seems unlikely that there's a non-jargon alternative to "*howler*" for a correct result arrived at through unsound reasoning.

Therefore, non-jargon terms for this concept will likely need to be constructed using multiple words.

Comment: I previously answered this question, but looking back at it, it seems that the question was clarified in an edit.  This answer is meant to address the clarified version of the question.

Comment: I wish this had been addressed on math.SE. I have never heard of 'howler' used in math as 'true but  unsoundly supported'. If anything 'howler' might be applied to a terribly mistaken proof attempt of an otherwise established theorem only because it is something 'obviously wrong to everyone else' (which is what a 'howler' is. 'Badly supported truths' are a very small subset of howlers in math. I distrust that the sentence in wikipedia faithfully represents what is in the reference. What is a howler is the erroneous process, _not_ the truth being proven.

Comment: @Mitch: The Wikipedia page did appear to relate [what the 1959-book described a "_howler_" as](https://archive.org/details/fallaciesinmathe0000maxw_z1t0/page/8/mode/2up?q=howler&view=theater) in its "_Chapter 1: The Mistake, The Howler, and the Fallacy_".  That said, it did seem like an odd usage, and it looks like both of the references cited above (the PDF and Wikipedia article) have been taken down (though Wikipedia retains a sub-section for "_howler_" in a different article).  Might update/delete this answer later.

Answer (score 2):

For some values of religious belief, **faith** is going to be a term applied to an accurate assessment of G-d and Its relation to mankind without any solid rational basis for that assessment.

Obviously, atheists and/or Wittgenstein would take exception to the application of the word "true" to the knowledge being claimed.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57087/discussion-on-answer-by-lly-is-there-a-word-for-an-unjustified-true-belief).

Comment: @tchrist That's fine, but the post with the link to the OED entry could've stayed. In any case, @ others, the OED cite is available via the link in T. Christ's message.

Comment: The definition of faith your reasoning using is only 1 of at least 6 definitions for the word. I find that irresponsible and your post to be unnecessarily demeaning of those who have faith. You could stick to the facts. Mentioning atheism to help define your word is a polemic.

Comment: @tchrist Can we get this insecure whinge shunted to chat with the rest? or am I able to do that myself somehow?

Comment: A more serious objection to this answer is that 'faith' may be misplaced in certain situations: faith in a person who then lets you down, say. Unsubstantiated and _not_ 'true_.

Answer (score 2):

A [Gettier Case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gettier_problem).  Your knowledge or lack thereof is 'Gettiered' when it fails to correspond to JTB theory.

Answer (score 0):

In philosophy and logic we distinguish (after [Aristotle](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/aristotle-logic/#AriDedModValArg)):

- [Valid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Validity_(logic)) [argument](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Validity.html): argument that if premises are true so is conclusion. For example 'Earth is flat. If earth was flat people sailing would felt off the world. Therefore Columbus would felt off the edge' (note - no one  - at least no one educated or familiar with sailing - actually believed in Columbus days that Earth is flat).
- [Sound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soundness#Of_arguments) [argument](https://www.iep.utm.edu/val-snd/): argument that if premises are true so is conclusion and premises are true.
- Invalid argument: argument that is, well, invalid regardless if the premises/conclusions are true or not.
- Unsound argument: argument that is not sound so either premises are not true or the chain of logic is not true.

Conversely I'd describe the believe as "unsound but true". I assume that this is an answer you seek as you tagged by 'philosophy' and not 'single-word'.

Comment: Hello, Maciej. Can you add a linked and attributed reference supporting the above? If you can, _will_ you add it, please?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I added links. I'm too lazy to go to the original Aristotle to give exact reference.

Answer (score 0):

It would appear<sup>**1**</sup> that there is no single word that encompasses the meanings of *both* "lacking in justification" *and* "true". Therefore, a phrase must be used, and I would suggest "***unsubstantiated***" as the most appropriate word for the first part. Thus you could say that "*Jackie Chan is a martial artist*" is an ***unsubstantiated truth*** (or *...fact* or *...belief*).

This is, in my opinion, a better phrase than *unjustified truth*/*belief*/*fact* since I believe that latter carries connotations of *being wrong* in asserting the truth (or holding the belief etc.). *Unsubstantiated* just says we haven't shown it to be true or false.

The OED's entry for *unsubstantiated* links to the second sense of "[***un-***](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/208915#eid17130511)":

> **un**, *prefix*
>
> 2. Prefixed to past participles, forming adjectives expressing the fact that the specified action **has not been carried out**.

and its entry for [***substantiated***](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/339603):

> **substantiated**, *adj.*
>
> That has been substantiated (in various senses of the verb); given substance, made real. Now usually: (of a fact, claim, etc.) **verified, justified with evidence**.

(Emphasis mine in both cases). So an ***un**substantiated* fact or opinion is one where verification or justification *has* not happened. It does *not* imply that either *cannot* happen.

On the other hand, the OED's two most appropriate entries for [***unjustified***](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/214860) are:

> **unjustified**, *adj*
>
> 3.
>
> a. Of a person, group, etc.: lacking or unable to demonstrate good justification for an action, opinion, etc.; not vindicated or shown to be in the right; not exonerated from a charge, criticism, etc. Cf. justify v. 2a, 7a.
>
> b. Of an action, opinion, etc.: not clearly right, proper, or appropriate; lacking justification or good cause; unwarranted.

While these definitions do not *explicitly state* that verification/proof is *not* possible, the tone is far less neutral than for *unsubstantiated*. In addition, the etymology of *unjustified* points to the *first* sense of "[***un-***](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/208915#eid17120510)":

> **un**, *prefix*
>
> 1. Prefixed to adjectives to express a **negative** sense, forming adjectives (and derived nouns).

Together, these all point to *unsubstantiated* being the better word to express the *lack* of evidence (one way or another), whereas *unjustified* has strong connotations of their actually being evidence to the contrary.

---

<sup>**1**</sup> Based on no one having found evidence so far *for* such a word. Of course, lack of proof is *not* proof of a lack.

Comment: There's possibly no single-word answer that addresses both 'unjustified' **and** 'true'. This covers 'unjustified'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Probably true. You would have to use _unsubstantiated fact_, _...truth_ or _...belief_.

Comment: I was wondering about downvoting, but somebody else has done it; one downvote is enough to engender wariness.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I'm happy to delete if that's the consensus... For my future education, although the title/body ask for "_a word_", it isn't tagged as single-word-request. If, as seems the case, there _isn't_ a single word to cover exactly what the OP wants, is it wrong to suggest a two-word answer?

Comment: I'd only do so if I thought that the answer was really (one of) the best possible ways to express something. There have been discussions on Meta about the point you raise. I think that the English language comes before ELU, but ELU comes before some of the poor stuff that appears here. I've been disappointed with the answers here (though I doubt an appropriate single-word answer exists): if a longer phrase were allowed, OP's 'unjustified [but] true belief' would take some beating.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Thanks for the response... I now understand where you're coming from and pretty much agree. I've made an attempt at salvaging _unsubstantiated_ with reasoning on why I think it better (to me, it was the "most obviously appropriate" word as soon as I read the question). If sentiment is still against me, I'll cut my loses and delete the answer.

Answer (score -2):

I think you're looking for "Axiom".  An axiom is statement that's assumed to be true.

An axiom is generally used as a basis for further logical reasoning.

Comment: Yes, in the sense that there is no justification given for the axiom, even though usually there is much justification given for it for it to be considered a useful axiom.

Comment: The axiom's being assumed to be true isn't the same as its actually being true, which is what was being looked for here I think.

Comment: I don't think "an axiom is statement that's assumed to be true". P ≠ NP is widely assumed to be true but it is not an axiom of complexity theory. Axiom is quite literally the closest thing to justified truth in system as possible.

Answer (score -3):

**Belief**, if it was justified it could be called a 'measurement' or 'observation', or even 'scientific proof'.

Comment: OP is looking for that which is unjustified. How does your post answer the question has to be explained.

Comment: Especially in philosophy believe can have a bit different meaning then in everyday world or even mainstream science. I'm close to [Bayesian viewpoint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayesian_probability) so for me 'measurement', 'observation' and 'scientific proof' are type of believes, in Bayesian sense. Assuming OP was looking for domain-specific word belief would be quite confusing. [To clarify - yes, my believe in theory of evolution is close to 100% while my believe in celestial teapot is close to 0%]

Answer (score -5):

I would say it is a "hypothesis". A hypothesis is just an idea without anything to substantiate it, so I would say this is accurate. But I am willing to be wrong.

Comment: A hypothesis can be the basis for further knowledge but in and of itself is just a guess, you're right... but the term doesn't imply any truth behind its guess, only the belief that it's potentially the right answer to some problem or question.

Answer (score -5):

Sometimes when referring to religious people the term 'fundamentalist' is used as a sort of synonym to 'false believer'.

Comment: Please include a source for the definition that supports your answer.